# for loop: add seconds each time a loop is made

Tags: c#, for-loop

How can I add 300 seconds to this for loop each time an iteration is made?

what I need is simple but I cant focus.

my initial seconds = 14400 and the next loop I need to add 300 seconds.. so

```
loop 1: seconds = 14400
loop 2: seconds = 14700
loop 3: seconds = 15000
```

and so on...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 145; i++)
{
  int seconds = 14400;
  TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
  string time = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
  Chart1.Series["TARGET"].Points.AddXY(time, 0);
}
```

Comment: Use timer and count how many times it elapsed.

Comment: Have you tried anything? HINT: The solution involves multiplying `i` by 300. Or are you trying to make the actual execution time of the loop longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this `int seconds = 14400;` outside `for` loop. Per your post below code will add 300 seconds in each iteration.

```
int seconds = 14400;
for (int i = 0; i < 145; i++)
{
  seconds+= 300;
}
```

Comment: there you go. thanks!

Comment: Still doesn't allow him to use the hours/min/seconds of `TimeSpan`

Comment: I downvoted the original totally-unedited version because it left 2 of his 3 problems totally unsolved.  You edited while I commented about that, then you edited again.  I've removed _my_ downvote but someone else seems to have applied one.  Since he's still satisfied, I've totally reversed it to an upvote :)

Comment: @jeffdot, thanks for being honest. Also, see question owner's response to my answer. I think the code he posted is bit irrelevant to the post. the sole reason was scope of the variable being inside loop.

Comment: no no this actually helped me with what I was looking for. Thanks @Rahul.

Comment: Well if it helped you, and if you don't need the timespan from my example, then you really should accept one of the answers.  Fairness suggests it should be the one posted by @Rahul :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `TimeSpan.AddSeconds(300)` ?

```
t.AddSeconds(300);
```

Here:

```
    void example()
    {
        var t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(14400);

        for(int i = 0; i < 145; i++)
        {

            t.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));

            string time = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
            Chart1.Series["TARGET"].Points.AddXY(time, 0);
        }
    }
```